# How can i fill Anonymous type in list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, anonymous-types

I try to write some codes about Generate list from Anonymous type via below codes :

```
public static List<T> MakeList<T>(T itemOftype)
{
    List<T> newList = new List<T>();
    newList.Add(itemOftype);
    return newList;
}
```

But ERROR return me:

> A primary key field specified via the
>   KeyFieldName property is not found in
>   the underlying data source.  Make sure
>   the field name is spelled correctly.
>   Pay attention to the character case.

**Main.cs**

```
var Qry = from tableRaletions in taskMaints.TaskRelations
    where tableRaletions.TaskId == Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text) && tableRaletions.RelTypeId == 12
    select new
    {
        tableRaletions.RefMaintenance.code,
        tableRaletions.RefMaintenance.shortdesc
    };
GridMaintenanceData.DataSource = SetCalculatedTaskField.MakeList(Qry);
GridMaintenanceData.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point of your extension method as there is already a ToList extension method and that will create a list of your anymous type, what your method will do is create a list, with a single item in it that is an IQueryable of your anonymous type.  Secondly the error is saying that  GridMaintenanceData has a property called KeyFieldName and you have specified a fieldname in there that does not exist within the datasource you are binding to it, probably because of your silly MakeList method.

Do this instead:

```
var Qry = from tableRaletions in taskMaints.TaskRelations
    where tableRaletions.TaskId == Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text) && tableRaletions.RelTypeId == 12
    select new
    {
        tableRaletions.RefMaintenance.code,
        tableRaletions.RefMaintenance.shortdesc
    };
GridMaintenanceData.DataSource = Qry.ToList();
GridMaintenanceData.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

You've specified a KeyFieldName that does not exist in your DataSource. Exactly what the error says. As far as I can tell from your example, this is nothing to do with the population of your generic list.

From your example, I'm guessing your primary key is `RelationId` and your `KeyFieldName` is set to that property. So just change ensure RelationId is return in your select:

```
select new
{
    tableRaletions.RefMaintenance.RelationId // It's spelt `relations` by the way.
    tableRaletions.RefMaintenance.code,
    tableRaletions.RefMaintenance.shortdesc
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code:

```
public static List<T> MakeList<T>(T itemOftype)
{
    List<T> newList = new List<T>();
    newList.Add(itemOftype);
    return newList;
}
```

What don't you use `List<T>` directly? What's the purpose for `MakeList<T>`? And

```
SetCalculatedTaskField.MakeList(Qry)
```

can be more easy:

```
Qry.ToList();
```

Comment: It is worse than that the MakeList method simply returns a list containing a single item the itemOftype variable passed into it. `SetCalculatedTaskField.MakeList(Qry)` will return a list containing one item with `Qry` in it, it will not return a `Qry` as a list.